# Redirecting subdomain to ip:port

Tags: redirect, subdomain

You know how in computer programming, perfection is not even close to be perfect?

Well, I have my server running on port 8080. I did the redirections needed with iptables to redirect 80 to 8080.
So when i go to www.domain.com, it works well

I have a second server running on port 8081.
When i go to www.domain.com:8081, it works well.

Everything works! But hey, remember my first rule...

Now, I want to to access my second site by using www.sub.domain.com (or www.domain.com/sub, i don't care)
Basically, I want www.sub.domain.com (or www.domain.com/sub) to redirect to www.domain.com:8081

From now, what I understand is that if I had a second IP on my server, it would be very easy. But it's not a good solution, because I could want to have like 100 subdomains, and I don't want to pay for this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to install a reverse proxy to your webserver. Apache and Nginx are supporting this;

For instance, your webserver listens on port 80, and depending on the requested domain (in a serverblock for nginx, vhost for apache) you can ask him to internally redirect to a specific url:port.

for apache: (see "Using Virtual_host and mod_proxy together")
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

for nginx:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Nice, thanks!
Should definitely do the trick. I guess it'll replace my iptables rule for 80->8080 redirection?

Comment: it will, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need iptables or reverse proxy to achieve all this. Just configure your web server to properly listen to default ports and use virtual hosting to let server correctly resolve requests.

On Apache read this section https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ , is rather small.
Imagine in the future you need to listen for https also, add certificates etc. When using reverse proxy it will get messy and unnecessary in your case.